# Excel: How to use conditional format in other cell?

Tags: excel

How to use conditional format in cell A1 if `B1 = "foo"`.
Example, `B1 = IF("FOO";;)`, A1 is **yellow color**.
Is Excel 2007.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following coniditona format formula for cell A1

```
=($B$1="Foo")
```

[image]

*Note* That if you want to apply this to the entire column A then make the following two adjustments.

1 - change the formula to remove the $ from the row in the formula so that it reads `=($B1="Foo")`

2 - ensure that the formatting is applied to the entire column[image]